# How to Calculate the LineString distance in kilometers?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assuming I have the following LineString in any `document`:

```
{ 
    type: "LineString", 
    coordinates: [ 
        [ 53.3477, -6.2597 ], [ 51.5008, -0.1224 ], 
        [48.8567, 2.3508], [52.5166, 13.3833] 
    ] 
}
```

When rendering this line on a map the result is:

[image]

How can I get the total distance of this LineString in kilometers, using the mongodb GeoQuery features?

Comment: You could start here: [`GeoJSON-Tools#getDistance()`](https://github.com/MovingGauteng/GeoJSON-Tools/blob/e17ecb7d597e5738960d4262f7eb70754e11b582/src/geojson-tools.js#L336).

Comment: Do you know why this is not in the official mongodb documentation?

Comment: Because it isn't part of mongo.  It doesn't look like mongo provides a built-in mechanism to find `LineString` length.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Since I am using python on the backend, I need to find a LIB GeoJSON for python. Thanks guy.